# Error : An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions in Azure Web APP

Tags: azure, symfony, azure-web-app-service

I've a php application (symfony) hosted in `azure web app` with 2 slots `(staging and preprod)`

I deploy the application to staging slot using `Azure DevOps` pipeline. The application work fine.

But when i swap the staging and preprod slot, `a 500 internal server error` will appear when i inspect my application with browser.

I check the error in `\var\log\`:

```
[2021-03-18 18:33:13] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. " at D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 97 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.\r\n at D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\AbstractMySQLDriver.php:97, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.\r\n at D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:31, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.\r\n at D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:27)"} {"controller":"fos_oauth_server.controller.token:tokenAction","token":null}
```

The parameters are correct (work in staging slot , before swap)

The two slot use the same PHP version (7.2)

Any idea to resolve that ?

Regards

Comment: Does the error occur immediately after swap? Or does it run for a bit before throwing the error? Also, what's your App Service Plan? Are we taking B1, S1, P2V3, ..?

Comment: the error occur immediately after swap. 
I ve S1 Plan

Comment: If you restart the app after the slot swap, do you see this error?

Comment: the swap restart automatically the webapp ; also , i do a manual restart , but the same error message

Comment: I've seen this error before with SNAT port exhaustion. It is something that you can check by going to your web app management blade in the portal, choosing Diagnose and Solve Problems, then type in "Snat" to see a list of tools that will diagnose port exhaustion.

Comment: Some configuration elements follow the content across a swap (not slot specific), whereas other configuration elements stay in the same slot after a swap (slot specific). Example - Always On settings is Slot specific. 

Settings that are swapped:

Web sockets are swapped. 
App settings (can be configured to stick to a slot) - make it not sticky/clone and check.

Comment: i dont use application setting in my slots. the two slots use the same database